# Given a sample proportion x and sample size y, how can one compute the probability that the population proportion is less than a certain value z?

Tags: statistics

It makes sense that the expected value would simply be the sample proportion, but how would one compute the probability that the population proportion is below a certain value? For example, if a survey yielded a sample proportion of .3 with a sample size of 300, how could I compute the probability that the population proportion is below .4?

Answer (score 0):

If you are treating the population proportion as a random variable then you may need a Bayesian approach

For example, if you start with a Beta prior for the population proportion of $B(\alpha,\beta)$ and see $300\times 0.3=90$ successes and $300-90=210$ failures, then your posterior distribution would be $B(\alpha +90,\beta+210)$ and have mean $\frac{\alpha+90}{\alpha+\beta+300}$

With $\alpha=\beta= \frac12$ (a Jeffreys prior) this would give a probability of being below $0.4$ of about $0.9998378$.  A uniform prior with $\alpha=\beta= 1$ would give about $0.9998259$ and an improper Haldane prior (with mean $0.3$) with $\alpha=\beta=0$ would give about $0.9998490$